# The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv3D object at 0x000001D009782400>

Tags: keras, instance, typeerror, layer, convolution

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      1 model= tf.keras.models.Sequential()
----> 2 model.add(Conv3D(64 ,kernel_size =(3,3,3) ,strides = (1,1,1), padding = 'same',input_shape=(input_shape) ,activation = 'relu'))
      3 model.add(Conv3D(64 , kernel_size = (3,3,3) ,strides = (1,1,1) , padding = 'same' , activation = 'relu'))
      4 model.add(MaxPooling3D(pooling_size = (2,2,2) , strides= (2,2,2)))
      5 model.add(Conv3D(128 , kernel_size = (3,3,3) ,strides = (1,1,1) , padding = 'same' , activation = 'relu'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [`tf.keras`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras) while you have added `Conv3D` layer from `keras.layers.convolutional.Conv3D`.

Change your layer import to:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv3D
```

Comment: again its shows an error    File "<ipython-input-2-33f6aec1e6e5>", line 4
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv3D,
                                       ^
SyntaxError: trailing comma not allowed without surrounding parentheses

Comment: model.add(tf.keras.layers.layers.Dropout(0.25))                                                                      error :module 'tensorflow.keras.layers' has no attribute 'layers' for dropout  layer

Comment: You really need to read [TF documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs) and go through some [python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) tutorials first.